# Excel VBA to check a list of values against a range and return a set value in another column

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to enter a value of "Yes" in column V should the value of column P match any of the values in a set list.

Sheet "Filters" contains the list of values in column P.

Sheet "Compiled Data" is where I hope to check column P against the list and then enter "Yes" in Column V for the same row.

I attempted an index/match function and a For/with function but perhaps I am not fully grasping each action within these functions or need to combine them. I am new to VBA and have referenced this site for several months now to answer most of my questions but this one is stumping me.

Comment: If you just want to check if the value of column V is present in any cell of column P, just use COUNTIF. It will return 0 if not, or return the number of matches

Comment: Its not just about knowing if the cell contains the value. I am applying the list as a filter against two independent columns that would remove unknown needed values if strictly filtered by the list. I will run this check against both columns to return a Yes in column V and then filter out the blanks in column V to keep only the rows needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### VBA Lookup

**Excel**

- Note that this could also be handled using the following Excel formula in cell `V2`:

  ```
  =IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(P2,Filters!P:P,0)),"Yes","")
  ```

**VBA**

```
Option Explicit

Sub VBALookup()
    
    ' Destination
    Const dstName As String = "Compiled Data"
    Const dFirst As Long = 2
    Const dLookup As String = "P"
    Const dResult As String = "V"
    Const dString As String = "Yes"
    ' Source
    Const srcName As String = "Filters"
    Const sFirst As Long = 2
    Const sLookup As String = "P"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Declare Last Row for both worksheets.
    Dim LastRow As Long
    ' Source
    Dim src As Worksheet
    Set src = wb.Worksheets(srcName)
    LastRow = src.Cells(src.Rows.Count, sLookup).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim sRng As Range
    Set sRng = src.Cells(sFirst, sLookup).Resize(LastRow - sFirst + 1)
    ' Destination
    Dim dst As Worksheet
    Set dst = wb.Worksheets(dstName)
    LastRow = dst.Cells(dst.Rows.Count, dLookup).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim dRng As Range
    Set dRng = dst.Cells(dFirst, dLookup).Resize(LastRow - dFirst + 1)
    Dim ColumnOffset As Long
    ColumnOffset = dst.Columns(dResult).Column - dst.Columns(dLookup).Column
    ' Write Result String ('dString') to Destination Result Range.
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In dRng.Cells
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(cel.Value, sRng, 0)) Then
            cel.Offset(, ColumnOffset).Value = dString
        End If
    Next cel
    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Lookup finished successfully.", vbInformation, "Success"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You are amazing! This worked first try and I was able to adjust to run against the second column to get the exact result. Thank you so much!